# Retrieving Firestore data in ListView but Failing

Tags: flutter, firebase, listview, google-cloud-firestore

Currently struggling to make a ListView data retrieved from Firestore.
I am trying to get "kids name" saved under in the firestore as linked photo.
[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdw1T.png)

No error message is shown up but the data is not retrieved correctly and shown blank screen...hope anyone can correct my code!
and here is my code:

```
class kidsNamePick extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _kidsNamePickState createState() => _kidsNamePickState();
}

class _kidsNamePickState extends State<kidsNamePick> {
  List<Memo> kidsnamelist = [];
  Future<void>fetchMemo()async{
    final kidsnames = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('useraccount').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('kidsname').get();
    final docs = kidsnames.docs;for (var doc in docs){
  Memo fetchMemo = Memo(kidsname: doc.data()['kids name'],
  );
  kidsnamelist.add(fetchMemo);}
    setState(() {

    });}
  @override
  void initState(){
  super.initState();
  fetchMemo();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Add/Select Kids'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: kidsnamelist.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(kidsnamelist[index].kidsname),
            );
          },
        )

    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to call `future` method is using `FutureBuilder`, first change your `fetchMemo` to this:

```
Future<List<Memo>> fetchMemo() async {
    try {
      final kidsnames = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('useraccount')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection('kidsname')
          .get();
      final docs = kidsnames.docs;
      return docs
          .map((doc) => Memo(
                kidsname: doc.data()['kids name'],
              ))
          .toList();
    } catch (e) {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

then change your build method to this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add/Select Kids'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Memo>>(
        future: fetchMemo(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Loading....');
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                List<Memo> data = snapshot.data ?? [];
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(data[index].kidsname),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfectly worked!!!